# Exponential Order: $\forall t>M$ or $\forall t>0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

The following comes from the discussion of Laplace transformation in ODE.

> Let $f(t)$ be piecewise continuous on $[0, \infty)$ and of exponential
>   order. Prove that there exist constants $K$ and $\alpha$ such that
>   $|f(t)| \leq K e^{\alpha t}$ for all $t \geq 0$.

I find this result amazing. A function having an exponential order only requires $|f(t)| \leq K e^{\alpha t}$ for all $t \geq M$. The above result means that if such $M$ exists, the whole function should be also of exponential order. Then $f(x)=\frac 1x$ is also of exponential order? How do we prove the above statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I entreat you to consider the fact that $f(x) = 1/x$ is defined on $(0, \infty)$, but not on $[0, \infty)$.  Cheers!

Comment: Every piecewise (bounded) continuous function such that $|f(t)|\leqslant Ke^{at}$ for every $t\geqslant M$ is such that $|f(t)|\leqslant K'e^{at}$ for every $t\geqslant0$, for some suitable $K'\geqslant K$, hence the two notions coincide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piecewise continuous on $[0, M]$ implies bounded on $[0,M]$. Note that $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is not piecewise continuous on $[0,\infty)$, since it is not defined at 0. But moreover, it cannot be  extended to a piecewise continuous function.